# Function of a dual space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Dual spaces are coming up in my self studies now. after many sources and lecture videos I still don't feel confident I understand.

Can someone help correct any misunderstanding and or confirm my current understanding.

A dual space is a space of all functions that satisfy the definition of a vector space ( you can recycle the definition of a vector space )

Does it just serve as a definition for functions that provide basis transformations?

Functions take a vector as argument and return a new vector? or a scalar? Both possibilities? (several lectures talked about mapping vectors the real numbers. others implied it returns a full vector.

If it contains all possible vectors, but does not index them in any useful way then how is it useful. I can't use them by referencing an index number. I still have to define the function myself. so isn't "dual space" just a classification of function such that "dual space function" satisfy certain criteria.

As you can probably tell I'm a programmer. I am falling in love with math but sometimes the language and abstract nature causes seg faults in my brain lol.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Given a real vector space $V$, a linear transformation $T: V \to \mathbb{R}$ is a single element of the dual space $V^*$.  With an obvious addition and scaling, $V^*$ is itself a vector space.

Comment: The dual space $V^*$ of a vector space $V$ is the set of all *linear functionals* on $V$, where a linear functional is just a linear transformation that maps into the real numbers. Like Randall said, you can define addition of two linear functionals, and scalar multiplication on linear functionals to turn $V^*$ into a vector space of its own. Dual spaces get more interesting in infinite dimensions.

Comment: If you need to be convinced this may be important, integration is an element of a dual space.  E.g., $\int_0^1 (-) \ dx: P_n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a linear functional, where $P_n$ is the vector space of polynomials of degree at most $n$.  If you like infinite-dimensional spaces, enlarge the domain to $C[0,1]$, the vector space of real-valued continuous functions with domain $[0,1]$.